# Auto-Adjust the Width of Excel Columns with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying that my columns will auto-adjust according to the data but they will provide me an error is there a possible way that my data are fit in the excel file they show me this error `ValueError: Shape of passed values is (1, 12), indices imply (1, 1)` is there any way to solve these error kindly check it if there is any visible solution for it

indices imply (1, 1)` is there any way to solve these error kindly check it

```
import enum
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Safari/537.3"
}
r = requests.get("https://www.fleetpride.com/parts/otr-coiled-air-hose-otr6818")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html5lib")
raw_json = ""
for table_index,table in enumerate( soup.find_all("script")):
    if('CCRZ.detailData.jsonProductData = {"' in str(table)):
        x=str(table).split('CCRZ.detailData.jsonProductData = {"')
        raw_json = "{\""+str(x[-1]).split('};')[0]+"}"
        break
      
      
req_json = json.loads(raw_json)
# with open("text_json.json","w")as file:
#     x=json.dump(req_json,file,indent=4)

temp = req_json
cat=temp['product']['prodBean']['friendlyUrl'][:11]
catu=temp['product']['prodBean']['friendlyUrl'][11:55]
catk=temp['product']['prodBean']['friendlyUrl'][56:71]
cup=temp['product']['prodBean']['friendlyUrl'][72:]
title=temp['product']['prodBean']['name']
specification=temp['product']['prodBean']['sku']
spec1=temp['product']['prodBean']['productSpecsS'][15]['specValue']
spec2=temp['product']['prodBean']['productSpecsS'][30]['specValue']
spec3=temp['product']['prodBean']['productSpecsS'][28]['specValue']
spec4=temp['product']['prodBean']['productSpecsS'][29]['specValue']
spec5=temp['product']['prodBean']['productSpecsS'][27]['specValue']
spec6=temp['product']['prodBean']['productSpecsS'][18]['specValue']
spec7=temp['product']['prodBean']['productSpecsS'][19]['specValue']
spec8=temp['product']['prodBean']['productSpecsS'][20]['specValue']

fea=spec6+spec7+spec8

spec11=temp['product']['prodBean']['ECrossReferencesS'][0]['Interchange_Part_Number__c']
spec12=temp['product']['prodBean']['ECrossReferencesS'][1]['Interchange_Part_Number__c']
spec13=temp['product']['prodBean']['ECrossReferencesS'][2]['Interchange_Part_Number__c']
spec14=temp['product']['prodBean']['ECrossReferencesS'][3]['Interchange_Part_Number__c']
spec15=temp['product']['prodBean']['ECrossReferencesS'][4]['Interchange_Part_Number__c']
spec16=temp['product']['prodBean']['ECrossReferencesS'][5]['Interchange_Part_Number__c']

cross=spec11+spec12+spec13+spec14+spec15+spec16

wev=[]
web={
    'category':cat,
    'sub_category':catu,
    'sub_category1':catk,
    'sub_category2':cup,
    'name':title,
    'Model_No':specification,
    'VMRS':spec1,
    'width_each':spec2,
    'Quantity':spec3,
    'Height_each':spec4,
    'cross_reference':cross,
    'feature':fea
    
}
# print(web)

wev.append(web)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(1, 12)),columns=wev)
# print(df)
df.to_csv('second.csv', index=False, encoding='utf-8')
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, the following code should work:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test_file.xlsx') 
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='test_sheet', index=False, na_rep='NaN')

for column in df:
    column_width = max(df[column].astype(str).map(len).max(), len(column))
    col_idx = df.columns.get_loc(column)
    writer.sheets['test_sheet'].set_column(col_idx, col_idx, column_width)

writer.save()
```

Comment: Dont forget: "pip install xlsxwriter"
Otherwise you receive an error: AttributeError: 'Worksheet' object has no attribute 'set_column'